# System.Timers.Timer need to get back to 'Main' thread

Tags: c#, timer

I have a Class(call it 'Foo') that has a System.Timers.Timer(call it 'myTimer').

Foo wraps unmanaged non thread-safe code.

On myTimer.Elapsed I need to use Methods in Foo.

Right now myTimer is trying use Foo's Methods on worker threads and this isn't working.

I need to get back to the thread that contains Foo' Methods.

How do I accomplish this?
FYI, Foo's Methods are in a non-UI thread.

Comment: "Foo is a non-UI thread" doesn't make sense, your class isn't a thread. Do you mean that "Foo" has a dedicated thread that all invocations on Foo should be run in?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If Foo is not a UI thread and you need to invoke code to execute on it from a different thread you will need to capture the synchronization context which executes Foo and then invoke your code from the timer on it.

Take a look at the [SynchronizationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.aspx) class. You can either [Post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.post.aspx) (asynchronously) or [Send](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.send.aspx) a delegate to be executed on a specific, previously captured, synchronization context.

You may also want/need to look into the [ExecutionContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.executioncontext.aspx) class. In particular: [ExecutionContext.Capture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.executioncontext.capture.aspx) and [ExecutionContext.Run](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.executioncontext.run.aspx)